# Ruby Call by reference is not working in each function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
excluded = "a", " an", " the", " at", " in", " on ", "since"     
temp = excluded.split(",").each {|val|  val = val.strip}
```

But I am getting the same array. Its not striping. I need to do this in single line

i need the output in temp like ["a", "an", "the", "at", "in", "on", "since"]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please show what your intended output is supposed to be.

Comment: i need the output in temp like ["a", "an", "the", "at", "in", "on", "since"]

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: split is used to split a string into an array, but you already started with an array. Naren's answer below does what you want.

Comment: I t seems that some one minus vote to my question. I Strongly believe that my question is genuine and it will help other ruby lerners. If u are free plz express your thoughts too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000231) `Array#each` returns the original receiver (`ary.each {|item| block } → ary`). What you want — as others have already pointed out — is [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249).

Also your current code should raise a `NoMethodError` because of calling split on an array. Assuming that `excluded` is a string, the following will work:

```
excluded.split(",").map(&:strip) #=> ["a", "an", "the", "at", "in", "on", "since"]
```

Instead of using `strip` you can also just change what you split on:

```
excluded.split(/,\s*/) #=> ["a", "an", "the", "at", "in", "on", "since"]
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, you have just done a fantastic job. Thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 temp =  ["a", " an", " the", " at", " in", " on ", "since"].map(&:strip)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this?:

```
excluded = ["a", " an", " the", " at", " in", " on ", "since"]
stripped_excluded = excluded.collect{ |i| i.strip }
```

or shortcut:

```
stripped_excluded = excluded.collect(&:strip)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the easier way:

```
temp = excluded.map(&:strip)
p temp
```